# Any way to optimize heavy image resizing with Intervention Image?

Tags: php, laravel, gd, intervention

I have an upload form which allows multiple files to be selected. The original files are quite heavy - approx. 10MB each.

Each uploaded file goes through the same resizing and saving process:

```
<?php

    $file = $request->file('qqfile'); // Huge JPG file in the request
    $image = Image::make($file); // Building an Intervention Image object

    $sizes = array(2560, 1980, 1366, 1024, 768, 480, 320);

    foreach ($sizes as $size) {
        $image = $image->widen($size->width);
        Storage::put('public/image_'.$size.'.jpg', $image->encode('jpg', 90));
    }
```

Now, my understanding is that in the `foreach` loop it's the 10MB, original image object that's being reused. So, during each iteration, the 10MB image object gets resized to a smaller size - e.g. from `4200x2460` to `320x187` in the last iteration, and then saved on the disk.

If I'm correct (am I?) then it's not very efficient, as the GD library operations are quite expensive and the server CPU can get hit stronger than it should.

**Is there any way I can optimize the resizing process?** E.g. for each iteration use already-resized image object, instead of the huge original one?

I would avoid this, though: `resize - save - read from disk - resize again`, as the disk I/O can get hit as well. What I have in mind is this: `resize the original - resize to the next size - ... - resize the last size, then save each`. This means I need a way to store a resized Intervention object in a variable, but not save it yet (as it will be saved in the last step).

Does this make sense? Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: i would assume that since the original is already in memory then you are not saving any resources by trying to use the resized image.  just use different variable here `$image = $image->widen($size->width);`  like `$r_image = $image->widen($size->width);`

Comment: True, but resizing itself is an expensive operation. It would be nice to be able to resize something smaller each time, than starting with the way-too-big image to get a `320px` width.

Comment: Worth a try, with the local variable.

Comment: Side note: You're going to lose additional quality on each iteration if you don't use the original image.